# How to login to my Ubuntu desktop like in Windows?

Tags: firefox, login-screen, auto-login

Today I tested something in 12.04. I have Automatic login enabled with password. So When I login a window pops up asking for the password. But I tested the following. I clicked cancel twice in the pop up window so the window disappears for a while then I opened my Mozilla Firefox browser I went straight to Edit > Preferences > Saved passwords. I clicked show passwords and Voilá I had access all my account passwords without logging into  Ubuntu.

Is this a bug or what? Is there a solution to make Ubuntu like in windows when a login screen comes up, I type my password than I access my desktop. It looks like that in Ubuntu the desktop and my files aren't blocked. Is there a solution to block everything while I type the password.

Comment: This is not a bug. Your passwords stored in Firefox have nothing to do with your user account under Ubuntu, which in turn has nothing to do with your root password. But there is an ongoing debate to move Firefox' password management to the Ubuntu wallet. Anywho, with auto-login enabled, everyone has access to your password wallet as well.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of Automatic Login is that it will not ask you for passwords during login. But anything that requires root user (aka admin) privileges, will not be possible and will still ask you for password confirmation. (Such installing new software, updating the system, etc...)

The password manager in Firefox has nothing to do with your Ubuntu account password. It only saves the passwords you save for websites.

As a suggestion, do not use the same password for everything. And if you want to type your password during login, you need to disable the automatic login.

Go into the User Accounts, in the top right there will be a `Unlock` button, click it and type your password and then disable the Automatic Login.

Answer (score 1):

You can go insto System Settings, User Accounts and turn off automatic login in your account, then you'll be shown lightDM Loging Manager everytime you boot your Ubuntu instalation